# Filling a container with iterators from another container

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a `std::map<int, int>` and a `std::list<std::map<int, int>::const_iterator>`.

Can I use an STL-algorithm to fill the `list` with all the iterators from the `map` in order? 
I don't want to use an explicit loop if possible.

Comment: You can't do this without a loop being involved. Even `std::copy()` uses a loop.

Comment: @Galik Presumably he means explicit loops.

Comment: @Galik: Yes. I thought about nice written code. In one line using STL. I know that inside I need to use loop by I want to hide it.

Comment: I think I'd take a step back. Why, exactly, do you believe you need a `std::list<map<int, int>::iterator>`? This sounds highly suspect to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithms in the STL call functors with values, not with iterators.
If you are obsessed with avoiding explicit loops then you might try to use [`iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) with an iterator as a value:

```
list.resize(map.size());
std::iota( std::begin(list), std::end(list), std::begin(map) );
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fe6dba5228faeca).